# Can't connect neo4j shell to local server

Tags: neo4j

I've installed neo4j 2.0.0 via homebrew and started the server. I'm able to access the webadmin console at port 7474 but when I run `neo4j-shell -host localhost -port 7474` I get:

```
    non-JRMP server at remote endpoint
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:248)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:341)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RmiLocation.getBoundObject(RmiLocation.java:253)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.findRemoteServer(RemoteClient.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.<init>(RemoteClient.java:55)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.<init>(RemoteClient.java:43)
    at org.neo4j.shell.ShellLobby.newClient(ShellLobby.java:165)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.startRemote(StartClient.java:295)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.start(StartClient.java:173)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.main(StartClient.java:125)
```

Help?

Answer (score 5):

Two years later and @jjaderberg's  answer is still relevant. I'm on Neo4J v3.1.1 right now and when installing via Homebrew, the neo4j.conf file makes no reference to the default port being 1337. In researching this further, Neo4js is deprecating use of the neo4j-shell in favor of cypher-shell, and by extension remove's the need for the 1337 port.

According to https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/ports/
"The neo4j-shell tool is being deprecated and it is recommended to discontinue its use."

Comment: `cypher-shell -u neo4j -p password -a bolt://localhost:1234` works great (use your own credentials and port, obviously)

Answer (score 0):

```
non-JRMP server at remote endpoint
```

means that it turns out turning on SSL was required.

Comment: @PeterMorris Better late than never, edit neo4j.conf, probably located in `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf` and then restart the neo4j service, probably using `systemctl restart neo4j`.

Comment: @JochemKuijpers I don't use neo4j any more :)

Comment: @PeterMorris I figured it wouldn't be relevant for you anymore, but since it showed up in my Google search, it might help someone someday.

Answer (score 0):

The default port for neo4j-shell is 1337, but if you are running the shell on the host computer you don't need to use a remote connection at all, try running it either without arguments at all or with `-path path/to/your/db`.