# Neo4j shell connect to local server

Tags: neo4j

**Update**: wrt. Neo4j 2.1.6 cf. http://goo.gl/LI18ao

As a follow up to [Can't connect to neo4j shell to local server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448081/cant-connect-neo4j-shell-to-local-server).

Installed neo4j-community-2.1.5 and started the server:

```
$ neo4j start
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [13088]... waiting for server to be ready.............................................................................. OK.
http://localhost:7474/ is ready.
```

Then tried to connect via the shell:

```
$ neo4j-shell 
ERROR (-v for expanded information):
    Connection refused
```

with the following expansion:

```
$ neo4j-shell -v
ERROR (-v for expanded information):
    Connection refused
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 172.24.46.19; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:129)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.welcome(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.AbstractClient.sayHi(AbstractClient.java:215)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.findRemoteServer(RemoteClient.java:63)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.<init>(RemoteClient.java:55)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemoteClient.<init>(RemoteClient.java:43)
    at org.neo4j.shell.ShellLobby.newClient(ShellLobby.java:165)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.startRemote(StartClient.java:297)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.start(StartClient.java:175)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.main(StartClient.java:120)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 14 more
```

Then I **disconnected my Laptop from LAN** and tried successfully again:

```
$ neo4j stop
Stopping Neo4j Server [13088].... done
$ neo4j start
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [13818]... waiting for server to be ready........................ OK.
http://localhost:7474/ is ready.
$ neo4j-shell
Welcome to the Neo4j Shell! Enter 'help' for a list of commands
NOTE: Remote Neo4j graph database service 'shell' at port 1337

neo4j-sh (?)$
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the shell doesn't try to connect localhost but your external IP address? Perhaps something wrong with the IP resolution? (/etc/hosts or DNS).

You can provide a `-host 127.0.0.1` parameter to the shell, perhaps that helps?

Comment: Ironically, after installing the neo4j-shell-tools the error disappeared. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt: 
[image]

C:\Users\nsh004\Documents\Neo4j>Neo4jShell -path C:\Users\nshinde004\Documen ts\Neo4j\Demo1 -file load.cql

This worked for me. we have to provide the path for database. Once I provided it worked!! :-)